Substack Publication Custom Domain and Cloudflare: Error 1014
I just set my domain evancarroll.com (which I've had for decades) with Substack using my new Substack Publication. I did this using a CNAME at substack.evancarroll.com. However when I browse to it, I see

Error 1014 Ray ID: 8f9e516d9e474fba • 2024-12-30 01:39:47 UTC
CNAME Cross-User Banned

This is what the screen of the error looks like,


I don't think this should have been migrated, fyi. My feeling is that this is a bug in Substacks UI more than a Webmaster thing. But if Webmasters wants it here, I'm cool with it. Hope it helps someone in the future!

Click Save and Apply
For me the problem was because at the bottom of the screen there was a little orange button that said "Save and Apply" (pretty sure that's what it said anyway. It was below the fold. The instructions to set up Cloudflare came before I clicked "Save and Apply"
After clicking it said,

Good news!
Your DNS records look good from our end. Our system will do a few more checks and your new domain will become active soon.
You will get an email when your domain becomes active.


And that was it!
